# Adding C library to Makefile

Tags: altcoin-development, compiling, c

I am developing an altcoin using a new PoW algorithm which is written in C to test the algorithm. I get compilation errors related to compiling the C code when trying to compile. How can I properly add the C code to the Makefile?

My fork is based of Bitcoin Core 0.12.1
I am compiling on Ubuntu 16.04

Here is the compilation error:

```
  CXXLD    bitcoind
  /usr/bin/ld: crypto/libbitcoin_crypto.a(crypto_libbitcoin_crypto_a- 
  rainforest.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `rf_crc32_table' can not be 
  used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
  crypto/libbitcoin_crypto.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

Here is how I added the files to src/Makefile.am:

```
# crypto primitives library
crypto_libbitcoin_crypto_a_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) 
$(BITCOIN_CONFIG_INCLUDES)
crypto_libbitcoin_crypto_a_CXXFLAGS = $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(PIE_FLAGS)
crypto_libbitcoin_crypto_a_SOURCES = \
   crypto/common.h \
   crypto/hmac_sha256.cpp \
   crypto/hmac_sha256.h \
   crypto/hmac_sha512.cpp \
   crypto/hmac_sha512.h \
   crypto/ripemd160.cpp \
   crypto/ripemd160.h \
   crypto/sha1.cpp \
   crypto/sha1.h \
   crypto/sha256.cpp \
   crypto/sha256.h \
   crypto/sha512.cpp \
   crypto/sha512.h \
   crypto/rainforest/rainforest.c \
   crypto/rainforest/rainforest.h
```

The files are rainforest.c and rainforest.h

Sorry for this question, I am a newbie in C and C++ developing, I come from Java and Python

EDIT: I didn't mention before that I linked rainforest.h by doing this:

```
extern "C"{ 
#include "crypto/rainforest/rainforest.h"
}
```

Comment: What/of which type is rf_crc32_tabl?

Comment: @MCCCS It is declared as `const uint32_t rf_crc32_table[256]`

Comment: If you include the functions with extern "C", then you should also declare them with extern "C" in the source file. Although your file is a c file, keep in mind that it'll be compiled by the cpp compiler.

Comment: @MCCCS Tried that, got the same error, not sure what to do but I think there may be a way to change the makefile so the compiler properly compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by compiling using `make -j2 CFLAGS="-fPIC"`
That solution isn't that convenient, I would rather modify the configure.ac or Makefile but it works.

Comment: One last guess: renaming the `rainforest.c` to `rainforest.cpp` might work.